# How to deploy to multiple environments using CodeCommit and Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I'm using CodeCommit as my repository for my code, as code-commit enables you to deploy your code to cross-accounts in another environment. I have set up a lambda function in my QA environment in the template.yaml using AWS SAM.

Where would I define the environment variables in the code pipeline so that the lambda function is can be deployed in the Prod environment in another account?

How would I define the variables so that when the staging lambda function is merged on the prod environment it takes the prod environment variables?

As it would not makes any sense to have the staging environment variables defined in the prod environment when the code is merged.

Would the environment variables be defined in the code-build?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: CD Demo Lambda
Resources:
  CDDemoLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: ./LambdaCode
      FunctionName: ApigatewayLambda
      AutoPublishAlias: ApiLambda
      Description: 'Lambda function validation'
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /getazs
            Method: get
      Environment:
        Variables:
          CONFIG_BUCKET: staging-bucket-name
          CONFIG_KEY: source-data-key-path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters and condition functionality in cloudformation to do that, for example, you will add a parameter section as follow:

```yaml
Parameters:
  Stage:
    Type: String
    Default: staging
    Description: Parameter for getting the deployment stage
```

then a mapping section with a map to hold the environment variables for all your stages

```yaml
Mappings:
  StagesMap:
    staging:
      CONFIG_BUCKET: staging-bucket-name
      CONFIG_KEY: source-data-key-path
    prod:
      CONFIG_BUCKET: prod-bucket-name
      CONFIG_KEY: source-data-key-path
```

then your function can use the variables based on which environment you are in:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: CD Demo Lambda
Resources:
  CDDemoLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: ./LambdaCode
      FunctionName: ApigatewayLambda
      AutoPublishAlias: ApiLambda
      Description: 'Lambda function validation'
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /getazs
            Method: get
      Environment:
        Variables:
          CONFIG_BUCKET: !FindInMap
            - StagesMap
            - Ref: Stage
            - CONFIG_BUCKET
          CONFIG_KEY: !FindInMap
            - StagesMap
            - Ref: Stage
            - CONFIG_KEY
```

Now when you are calling your sam to deploy command, you need to define which stage you are deploying to.
ex:

```sh
sam deploy --parameter-overrides Stage=prod
```

Your complete cloudformation template should look like this:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: CD Demo Lambda

Parameters:
  Stage:
    Type: String
    Default: staging
    Description: Parameter for getting the deployment stage

Mappings:
  StagesMap:
    staging:
      CONFIG_BUCKET: staging-bucket-name
      CONFIG_KEY: source-data-key-path
    prod:
      CONFIG_BUCKET: prod-bucket-name
      CONFIG_KEY: source-data-key-path


Resources:
  CDDemoLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: ./LambdaCode
      FunctionName: ApigatewayLambda
      AutoPublishAlias: ApiLambda
      Description: 'Lambda function validation'
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /getazs
            Method: get
      Environment:
        Variables:
          CONFIG_BUCKET: !FindInMap
            - StagesMap
            - Ref: Stage
            - CONFIG_BUCKET
          CONFIG_KEY: !FindInMap
            - StagesMap
            - Ref: Stage
            - CONFIG_KEY
```